# What is BTC-E CODE?

Tags: trading, btce

In the "Finances" tab on https://btc-e.com/ you can enter your BTC-E Code there.

What is this about?

Answer (score 4):

It is a redeemable code.
They can be obtained from BitInstant or AurumXChange.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Redeemable_code

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BTC-E

Think of it like a prepaid gift card code. If you have one, you can punch the code in, and a predefined amount appears in your account balance.

Comment: can you explain this in simple words? I don't understand the wiki page

Comment: Put simply. You get a code. That code allows you to transfer bitcoin, without using BTC addresses.

Answer (score 0):

BTC-e code is used to quickly transfer money between users BTC-e.com exchanges mainly in US dollar currency. This method minimizes the loss during conversion to cryptocurrency, and then reverse the conversion to dollars.